# .db file won't open on Visual Studio Code using sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I have a file in my SQL Directory that I am trying to open using sqlite3 on Visual Studio Code however when I use .open "C:\Users\17724\Documents\SQL\Global_Superstore.db" it will instead create a new file in the Users directory and label it "Users24DocumentsSQLGlobal_Superstore" as a .db file with 0 KB.[This is the .db file that is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JVzM.png) I emailed this database file from my Macbook so I can open it on my other Windows computer. I know that the file contains the data I'm looking for because I can open it with another program, Tableau, and review the contents. [This is the .db file I am trying to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrneD.png) I copied the path name directly from explorer using shift right click so I cannot have made any typos. I am running sqlite3 from terminal in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using WSL (Linux) terminal in VS Code you need to refer to file using its WSL path which is `/mnt/c/Users/17724/Documents/SQL/Global_Superstore.db` (assuming you did not change where WSL mounts your C: drive).

That file you mentioned is created likely because you already are in your user directory when terminal starts and when you use Windows path backslashes (`\`) are interpreted by shell as escape sequences.

You can easily figure WSL path of file using command `wslpath -a "C:\\Users\\17724\\Documents\\SQL\\Global_Superstore.db"` (note doubled backslashes to avoid unwanted escape sequences).

Comment: That makes sense! I used '/' instead and it worked. Thank you.